# How to create an AWS based simple web app that allows individualized user content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, user-controls, amazon-cognito, personalization

I want to create a simple notetaking web app with AWS. It should allow individual users to sign up and sign in to CRUD notes. Amazon Cognito almost worked. However, after signing in, all users can have access to all notes, instead of the notes created by the specific user. Can anyone provide some directions on how this should be done on AWS?

Comment: How about Role-based access control? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html#best-practices-for-role-based-access-control  If you use only S3 as note storage, you can use this way too. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Comment: Thanks, Shimo. This is helpful. I am thinking to use S3 for image, and GraphQL API  to store notes into Dynamo DB. How can I make the GraphQL API work?